# For loop with if statements

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I'm attempting to code an indicator variable in R, yes I'm using a for loop when I shouldn't

```
lch$clickIndicator <- rep(0, nrow(lch))
for (i in length(lch$clickIndicator)) {if (lch$PREV_CLICKS[i] > 0 || lch$IS_CLICK[i] == 1) {
  lch$clickIndicator = 1
} else {
  lch$clickIndicator = 0
}}


max(lch$clickIndicator)
```

Unfortunately the `max()` function is returning 0 after running the loop, I've tried various permutation of this code, including directly referencing each `lch$clickIndicator[i]` element, but nothing works. I'm obviously missing something simple.

Can anyone suggest how to get this for loop working, and even better, if there's a simple way to vectorize this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot (a) to index the output variable. Use `lch$clickIndicator[i]` instead of `lch$clickIndicator`. Another problem is (b) `for (i in length(lch$clickIndicator))`. You want `for (i in 1:length(lch$clickIndicator))`. Otherwise the functions are applied to the last row only.

```
lch$clickIndicator <- rep(0, nrow(lch))
for (i in 1:length(lch$clickIndicator)) {
  if (lch$PREV_CLICKS[i] > 0 || lch$IS_CLICK[i] == 1) {
    lch$clickIndicator[i] = 1
  } else {
    lch$clickIndicator[i] = 0
  }
}
```

---

You don't need a loop for this task but can use vectorized operations:

```
lch$clickIndicator <- as.integer(lch$PREV_CLICKS > 0 | lch$IS_CLICK == 1)
```

Comment: @SimonHayward See the update. There was another problem.

Comment: Thanks for that update. I've been learning Python and got my ranges confused! Thank you very much for a nice, clear answer.